# Apache Spark : Long Shuffle Read Blocked Time. Why?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have an 8-nodes Spark standalone cluster with a total of 880 GB RAM and 224 cores.

I just can't explain why the `Shuffle Read Blocked Time` is so long : about 20 minutes per task. Do you have an idea why ? What are the bottleneck in such case ?

To give more details, you can see bellow the details for stage :

[image: details for stage apache Spark]

The following `tasks metrics` from `Spark Ui` bellow :

[image: Summary completed tasks metrics from Spark UI]

The agregation per executor bellow :

[image: Agregation per executor metrics from Spark UI]

And the stage full DAG :

[image]

The executor tab :

[image]

The list of stages :

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740567/spark-shuffle-read-takes-significant-time-for-small-data could be related

Comment: Related to storage ? Yes it could be. Could you elaborate a bit please ? In fact, the underlying storage is GPFS (IBM equivalent to HDFS). And we can't have IBM FPO enable (so to be clear : no local disk for spark.local.dir, but the GPFS distributed filesystem is also used for spark local dir which might come with some latencies..)

Comment: Related to GC ? Yes it could be too. I have 8 executors (one executor = one node), so each executor has about 100GB free memory. I use the default GC. Do you have some tips here to enhance my ETL ? When I look to the GUI, "executors" tab, the "GC" column doesn't appear in red however

Comment: yup ..i was only pointing toward latencies/throughput but link posted above also hints about previous state executors having gc causing this issue

Comment: can you please check gc time in previous stage?

Comment: I have added at the end of my message the "executor tab". GC seems OK..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237109/discussion-between-vish-and-klun).

Comment: It might not be related to your issue, but I find 120GB spill memory quite suspicious

Comment: Could you please elaborate @BlueSheepToken ? :)

Comment: I am on my phone right now, I Can elaborate tomorrow. Meanwhile Can you try to increase the number of Shuffle partitions ?

Comment: Yes I will try to increase number of shuffle partitions tomorrow. For now, it is set to 2000 to process my 17 billions of rows

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the exact same problem. I disappears on restart of the cluster, but then the "Shuffle Read Blocked Time" gradually start increasing with each job.